# mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource and Notice: Undefined variable: DB

Tags: php, mysql

Here are the errors im getting

Warning: main(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/dwscodep/public_html/index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: DB in /home/dwscodep/public_html/index.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_query(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /home/dwscodep/public_html/index.php on line 17

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given in /home/dwscodep/public_html/index.php on line 17

```
 <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    require_once('lib/config.php');
    require_once('blocks/head.php');
    $error = array();


    if (isset($_POST['signin'])) {

    $username = stripslashes(trim($_POST['uname']));
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ebay_users WHERE username = '$username' and 
    password='$password'";

    $rs = mysql_query($DB,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($rs);

    if ($count > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $user = $row['username'];
            $ready_ebay = $row['eBayReady'];

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['eBayReady'] = $ready_ebay;
            $_SESSION['signedin'] = true;

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ebay_config WHERE user_id = $user_id ";
            //echo $sql;
            $resp = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $count = mysql_num_rows($resp);
            if ($count <= 0) {
                $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO ebay_config SET 
                user_id=$user_id,
                title_prefix='New',
                profit_percentage = 25,
                condition_id = '1000',
                price_formula = '001',
                dispatch_time = 1,
                max_quantity = 1,
                shipping_service ='UPSGround',
                shipping_type = 'Flat',
                payment_method='PayPal',
                return_accept_option = 'ReturnsAccepted',
                return_days = 'Days_14',
                listing_type = 'FixedPriceItem',
                listing_duration ='GTC'
                ";
                mysql_query($sql_insert) or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    } else {
        $error['count'] = '<div id="ErrorMsg" class="alert alert-error">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data- 
     dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                                Error! Invalid User Name Or Password
                                </div>';
        $signedin = false;
       }
       }
```

Comment: Important note: mysql_query is removed completely from PHP 7 - so u should shift to mysqli_query etc

Comment: Please stop. Get hold of any (fairly) recently published book or tutorial on PHP and MySQL, and start over. This code is archaic and  insecure.

Comment: its a old code from github im trying to update.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors here. First you need to set timezone value in your file or in your php.ini file. Then this error

```
Warning: mysql_query(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are required to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
```

will disappear.
If your are going add it in your php file,You need to add values according to your geo-location as below. For me it is

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Colombo");
```

And use mysqli_ instead of mysql, Then you will resolve some other few errors.